# Help with updating to from 13.10 to 14.04

Tags: apt, upgrade

When I run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update    
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I just get this error:

```
Calculating upgrade... Failed
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcogl15 : Breaks: libclutter-1.0-0 (< 1.15) but 1.14.4-3 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I'm really new to Linux/Ubuntu and I just can't figure out how to update libcogl15.

If I run the command

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then I get

```
Could not calculate the upgrade 

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. 

This can be caused by: 
* Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu 
* Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu 
* Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu
```

See my [/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log](http://pastebin.com/tTFsHPg1)

Comment: `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` does not upgrade to the newest version. You need to do `do-release-upgrade` as explained here: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html

Comment: I've tried that but still get the same issue see edited question. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I just did upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS from Ubuntu 13.10 through 'Software Updater' from Dash. The process was fully automatic, smooth, and seamless. Thanks a lot Ubuntu Team.

Comment: Exactly what happens when you use `do-release-upgrade`?

Comment: I've dwl the iso file and use that to install it and it work now.